# mysql check if username and password matches in database using laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have small issue with authentication when user try to login but the username and password not matched in table how can return to login page with error massage

**login.blade.php**

```
<form class="login-box animated fadeInUp" action="valdateData" method="POST" >
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="box-header">
        <h2>Log In</h2>
    </div>
     <label for="username">Username</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
    <br/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <br/>
    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    <br/>
    <a href="#"><p class="small">Forgot your password?</p></a>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/testgetvalue','OrdersController@GetValues');
Route::get('/ES','OrdersController@PrepareIndex');
Route::get('/loginForm','LoginController@ShowLoginPage');
Route::post('/valdateData','LoginController@checkValidate');
Route::post('login/{id}','LoginController@ShowErrorMassege');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public function ShowLoginPage()
{
    return view('/loginForm');
}

public function checkValidate(Request $request)
{

    $username=$request->input('username');
    $password=$request->input('password');
    $isVald=true;

    $checkValdate = \DB::table('authentications')
                    ->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])
                    ->get();

    if(count($checkValdate) > 0)
    {
        $isVald=true;
        session()->set('UserValidate','true');
        session()->set('username',$username);
        //$value=session()->get('test');
        // echo "session "+$value;
        return redirect('/es');
    } else {
        return redirect('/login/'.$isVald);
    }
}
```

in this part

```
return redirect('/login/'.$isVald);
```

how can return to login page with error message

thanks

Comment: you are using php artisan make:auth?

Comment: no i'm using custom  table

Comment: You could use the `with()` function. `return redirect('/login/'.$isVald)->with('status', 'Error message!');` Then you will have `status` in your session.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'username'=>'required|min:3|max:30',
        'password'=>'digits_between:1,5000',


    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', sprintf('Server failed provided data validation.Please try again and follow the validation rules as instructed.'));
    }
```

Here is a example of how you can do it, depends on your validatin rules. You can also define partials with a costum message foreach error, you should also use "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;" in your controller